# Change row colour in a datagrid based on the date

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid

I am currently using a datagridview in C# that is working correctly.

This datagridview has a checkbox field thats linked too a database, I am requiring all rows in the datagridview to be red until the checkbox is checked. Once the checkbox is checked the row will then turn green.

I am also requiring the checkbox field to be the only field in the datagrid that is not read only, but this isnt crucial at this stage. I hope you can offer me some suggestions.

Using visual studio 2010 in a windows forms application

Comment: WinForms, WPF, and ASP.NET *all* have a control called a `DataGrid`. Which one are you using?

Comment: Winforms in visual studio 2010

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to use the `DataGrid` control instead of the newer **`DataGridView`**? It provides more ways to customize the display of data, and would probably make this easier. The only reason you should still be using the older `DataGrid` control is if you need the hierarchical display of information from two related tables in a single control. More information on the differences is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171628.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to CellContentClick event.

Read the cell value when user clicks it. If the checkbox is set then get the row index from event handler and write the following line in event handler.

```
datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

Comment: That's an event of the **`DataGridView`** class, not the `DataGrid` as discussed in the question.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what im after. I shall acccept this answer.